# Calling an Objective-C method from Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS and I am not getting how to call an objectiveC method from Javascript using web view.

I have already tried this but it didn't work. Additionally, please help me with my objectiveC code.

```
function IosSuccess(transactionid)
{
alert("Transaction successful,transaction id :" +transactionid);
var ret = jsb.reflection.callStaticMethod("PaymentViewController","TransactionId:",""+transactionid);
}
```

Comment: I think you are calling this for getting responce from UIWebView?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call objective c method using JavaScript directly rather you have to use JavaScriptCore.framework and making an interface for call back will do the required task.